# What's the best way to dynamically generate a where clause?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I am writing a stored procedure that works with a heavy select statement. The stored procedure takes in about 15 parameters to act as a filter, all of which are NULLable.

There are two things the parameters generally do - check if x is between high and low or check if column value is in y.

My main concern is how I write the where clause.

Example: Dynamic SQL is notoriously slow, so I don't want to write the where clause and then pass it to exec.

I don't want to do `if High = null then High = max` because then I'll still have a between statement that takes up processing power and has no use.

I don't want to do an `(if High = null or X <= High)` because the null check would still be processed for every row and I heard rumors that would mess with indexes.

In short, I'm looking for guidance in the best practice that takes performance into account.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: What makes you say that Dynamic SQL is notoriously slow? Also, I would verify any rumors before I made design decisions based on them.

Comment: @Alex K: Would you believe that someone just IMed me exactly the same URL a few seconds ago? Thanks :)

Comment: @JSWork all that guys articles are great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dynamic SQL used to be slow because execution plans for dynamically generated SQL weren't cached.  This is no longer the case and execution plans for dynamic SQL queries will be cached as long as the query text is identical.  This means that you should:

- Use parameters to avoid your parameter values altering the query text
- Try to sort your where clauses so that they appear in the same order

As long as you do this then your query plans should be cached (one for each possible query variation) and dynamic SQL won't be any slower than any normal query.

---

Your other suggestions (setting various parameters to NULL) is to be avoided and may in fact perform quite badly - statements can only have one cached query plan, however the *optimal* query plan will depend on the parameters and may be very different depending on the values supplied.

For example one set of parameters might result in most of the table being returned, in which case a table scan might be optimal.  Another set of parameters might result in a single row being returned in which case a row lookup might be optimal.  SQL Server must choose to cache one of these two plans (probably the most optimal one based on the parameters supplied the first time the query is run), however whatever plan it chooses the query will probably perform badly in the opposite scenario.  (this is an over simplification, however I have seen variations of this happen and it can have a very significant performance impact).

Ultimately this will mean that either:

- Most of the time the query plan chosen probably wont be optimal, or
- You can force SQL Server to generate a new plan for each execution which always results in a reasonable execution plan, however eliminates the advantages of plan caching

The other disadvantage of your alternative aproaches is that it will result in a more complex query, which can make it difficult for the query optimiser to optimise the query properly.

For these reasons I'd say that dynamic SQL is definitely the better choice.

Answer (score 3):

If you use dynamic SQL with placeholders for the parameters instead of incorporating the parameters in the statement, and bind the parameters when you open the cursor, the statement can be cached and won't be slow.

From below comment: There will not be so many (yes, potentially 2 ^ 15 but in practice many fewer, perhaps more like 2 ^ 4 are used commonly) combinations of present and missing parameters; these can be cached. If the actual parameter values are included in the WHERE clause (which I've seen done), each query is unique and won't be cached.

Comment: AFAIK - As the OP is suggesting building up different WHERE clauses as the different search parameters are used (or not), the change in the WHERE clause will result in a lack of cached execution plan.

Comment: @Dems -- But there will not be so many (yes, potentially 2 ^ 15 but in practice many fewer, perhaps more like 2 ^ 4 are used commonly) combinations of present and missing parameters; these can be cached.  If the actual parameter values are included in the WHERE clause (which I've seen done), each query is unique and won't be cached.

Comment: With that added to your answer, I now agree :)

Answer (score 1):

One technique for dealing with a check for nullity in a `where` clause expression is to do something like this:

```
declare @myParameter int

select *
from dbo.foo t
where t.someColumn = coalesce( @myParameter , t.someColumn )
```

The optimizer can still use an index on `t.someColumn` and you avoid the `OR` operator (which is what usually bolluxes up the use of an index.

That's one thing to look at.

Another thing: I had to do the same thing in a previous job. The problem with coding it up naively is that you're likely to get poor performance for any one of a number of reasons:

- If the 1st query executed is executed with what you might describe as "non-standard" parameters, the cached execution plan is likely to perform poorly for more ordinary cases.
- With all those variables, the optimizer may select a query plan that's dialed in for a parameter that may not even be used most of the time.
- the list goes on...

What I wound up doing, was to instrument the stored procedure, log how it was being called. Once I had some baseline data, a little analysis showed me the 4 or 5 most common ways it was being used.

That allowed me to put add scenarios for each of these most common ways, so 90% of the callers got great performance, most of the rest got OK performance, and there was once special case that we couldn't do anything with (unless the DBAs were willing to recluster some of the tables involved in the selection...which seemed unlikely).

Also, you should assign the stored procedure parameters to local variables within the stored procedure. If you don't, the parameters passed affect how the execution plan is cached. By doing this, the value of the parameter becomes an expression and no longer affect the cachin of execution plans.

Further, be mindful of stored procedure recompilation. In a busy system, recompiles can have a deleterious effect on performance. If a stored procedure gets recompiled one or more times on every stored procedure call, the recompilation takes out compile locks that (A) prevent others from executing the stored procedure until the recompilation is complete, and (B) lock the various resources/dependencies involved in recompilation. In a busy system, your DBA is unlikely to look with favor on blocking.

Here's MSDN on [Execution Plan Caching and Reuse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055.aspx)

Hope this helps.